# Big Number representation -- Does this exist, and where?

Tags: number-theory

I am at the level of hobbyist, so please tolerate my naivete.

I am taking a sophomore-level math course, Discrete Math, and being introduced to some interesting concepts such as Big-O (Time Complexity of algorithms).  In thinking this stuff over, I stumbled across this equation:

```
number = n! + o^p + floor(q * log(r)) + s
```

where n, o, p, q, r, and s are all integers.  It occured to me that this may be the most effiecient way space-wise to represent very large numbers (or at least a very effiecient way), and perhaps a BigNumber software class could be built on it.  So my question: Is this equation extant in current literature, and if so, where should I look for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to represent integers of size $2^n$, you need $n$ bits.  There is no way around it, there are just too many of them.  If you are willing to represent them approximately, you can do things like the usual floating point where you store the exponent and mantissa.

The representation you give has a number of weaknesses.  First, it is not unique.  Given a number, there are many representations.  Second, it is hard to operate with-suppose you wanted to add or multiply two numbers in this representation.  Even comparing two numbers for which is larger is difficult.

Comment: "If you want to represent integers of size 2 n  , you need n  bits. There is no way around it" this sounds like a proven theorem, correct?  That is, is what you are telling me meant to indicate this has been proven, so no other equation would ever improve on space efficiency?

Comment: To represent numbers up to $2^n$, you need that many representations.  Since each bit has two possibilities, it takes $n$ of them to make that many-you multiply all the $2$'s together.  So yes, no representation can improve the space efficiency unless you give up on representing all the numbers.